# SQL base types: integer vs int?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, integer, int

For [query language (SQL) functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-sql.html), what's the difference between the `int` and `integer` [base types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/extend-type-system.html#AEN51720)?

How do you know?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Postgresql `int` and `int4` are aliases for `integer`, a signed four-byte integer

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-TABLE

Answer (score 8):

Int and Integer are the same

> "The keyword INT is a synonym for INTEGER"

Similarly

> "The keywords DEC and FIXED are synonyms for DECIMAL"

[Sql Numeric Documentation Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)